# Can't add UIImageView to to the IBOutletCollection

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iboutletcollection

I tried to find the solution, but I couldn't find anyone with the same problem.

I'm using Xcode 8.2.1, writing in Objective-C.

I'm actually having a problem with adding a UIImageView to IBOutletCollection. I'm trying to do it using the Interface Builder.

[dragging to connect ImageView with the Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giMjb.png)

I've already deleted any existing outlets of that ImageView.

I'm also adding screenshot of the header file of the MasterViewController - I guess everything is OK here.

[declaration of the collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Jnyl.png)

Thanks for help.

Comment: `IBOutletCollection(UIViewController)` should be `IBOutletCollection(UIImageView)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `IBOutletCollection(UIImageView)` instead of `IBOutletCollection(UIViewController)`